# What is "-1L" / "1L" in C?

Tags: c

What do "-1L", "1L" etc. mean in C ?

For example, in [ftell](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/ftell/) reference, it says

> ... If an error occurs, -1L is returned ...

What does this mean ? What is the type of "1L" ?

Why not return NULL, if error occurs ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The `L` specifies that the number is a `long` type, so `-1L` is a `long` set to negative one, and `1L` is a `long` set to positive one.

As for why `ftell` doesn't just return `NULL`, it's because `NULL` is used for pointers, and here a `long` is returned.  Note that `0` isn't used because `0` is a valid value for `ftell` to return.

Catching this situation involves checking for a non-negative value:

```
long size;
FILE *pFile;

...

size = ftell(pFile);
if(size > -1L){
    // size is a valid value
}else{
    // error occurred
}
```

Comment: Ok, i got it. Then how do I catch the situation where ftell returns -1L ?  --- if(ftell(fp) == -1L) {} ? or if(ftell(fp) == -1) {} ?

Comment: So, if L represents long, which characters represent other types? Is there a related reference on the net?

Comment: @Jevgeni, see [this list](http://c.comsci.us/etymology/literals.html).  It's not complete, though.  It's missing at least `L` for a `wchar_t` string.

Comment: @Jevgeni, some standard ones are `f` for `float` and `ul` for `unsigned long`, here's a [reference](http://c.comsci.us/etymology/literals.html)

Comment: @Mat: It's also partly incorrect, isn't it? In C the type of `'c'` is `int`, not `char`.

Comment: `NULL` is not a valid return value for `ftell`. `NULL` is only valid in pointer contexts and `ftell` does not return a pointer.

Comment: @R..: I never said `NULL` was a valid return value (in fact, I believe I said the opposite, admittedly the rationale was wrong), edited anyway, though.

Answer (score 6):

ftell() returns type *long int*, the L suffix applied to a literal forces its type to *long* rather than plain *int*.

NULL would be wholly incorrect because it is a macro representing a *pointer* not an *integer*.  Its value, when interpreted and an integer may represent a valid file position, while -1 (or any negative value) cannot.

For all intents and purposes you can generally simply regard the error return as -1, the L suffix is not critical to correct operation in most cases due to implicit casting rules

Comment: +1 for being the only person who seems to know the difference between pointers and integers.

Comment: Converting a null pointer to an integer doesn't *necessarily* yield `0`.

Comment: NULL does NOT represent a pointer, it is defined as 0, 0L or 0ULL, etc. That's why C++11 introduced nullptr. Consider: `int foo(const char*); int foo(unsigned long f); ... foo(NULL);`. That isn't going to call the one you expect if you think "NULL" is a pointer type.

Comment: @ksone:  In C (as the question is tagged) NULL is defined as `(void*)0`.  C++ does indeed define it as 0.  In C++ the use of NULL is discouraged (by Bjarne Stroustrup) in favour of literal zero exactly because it is a macro and may be incompatibly redefined.  C++ guarantees that an integer zero casts to an invalid pointer.  In either C or C++ however, NULL is defined with the *intent* that it is used as an invalid pointer value rather than an integer.

Comment: @KeithThompson: You think?  Either way, whatever it casts to might be a valid ftell() position which is more the point.

Comment: @Clifford: In C, `NULL` expands to an implementation-defined *null pointer constant*, which is either an integer constant expression with the value zero, or such an expression cast to `void*`. Both `0` and `((void*)0)` are valid definitions for `NULL` in a C implementation (so is `('-'-'-')`). Note that the outer parentheses are required; defining `NULL` as just `(void*)0` would cause problems with operator precedence.

Comment: @Clifford: Then you should update your question to say that. It currently claims that casting a null pointer to an integer *will* have value zero, which is misleading.

Comment: @KeithThompson:  Its not my question to update - you mean my answer.  The truth is I don't *know* that that is not the case - I was rather hoping that you would enlignten us.  The point about the definition of NULL in C is accepted - nonetheless the point stands that it is not intended to be used as an integer.  I don't think the precise language semantics add much to the general point that NULL should not be used to mean zero - it still *represents* a pointer even if it is not defined with one.  Besides this has stood for three years without comment - I shall consider changes in that context.

Comment: You're right, I meant "answer". The main point, that `NULL` should not be used as an integer, is of course correct. But (a) the standard says nothing about the result of converting a null pointer to an integer type (except that it's implementation-defined and "intended to
be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment", and (b) doesn't really matter in this case. And the question didn't say anything about casting the result. I suggest that your answer would be improved by deleting the second sentence of the second paragraph. (It's never too late.)

Answer (score 4):

It means to return the value as a long, not an int.

Answer (score 2):

That means -1 as a long (rather than the default type for numbers, which is an integer)

Comment: `long` *is* an integer type. I think you mean that the default type for integer *constants* is `int` -- but even that's an oversimplification.

Answer (score 2):

`-1` formated in `long int` is a `-1L`. Why not simple `NULL`? Because `NULL` in this function is a normal result and can't sygnalize error too. Why `NULL` in this function is a normal result? Because `NULL == 0` and `ftell` returns position in a stream, when you are on start of stream function returns `0` and this is a normal result not error, then if you compare this function to `NULL` to check error, you will be get error when you will be on start position in stream.

Comment: No, `NULL` is not a normal result for `ftell`. The `ftell` function returns a `long`, not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Editing today implies more details are still wanted.

Mark has it right. The "L" suffix is long. -1L is thus a long -1.

My favored way to test is different from Marks and is a matter of preference not goodness.

```
if ( err >= 0L )
    success
else
    error
```

By general habit I do not like looking for explicit -1. If a -2 ever pops up in the future my code will *likely* not break.

Ever since I started using C, way back in the beginning of C, I noticed most library routines returning **int** values return 0 for success and -1 on error. Most.

NULL is not normally returned by integer functions as NULL is a pointer value. Besides the clash of types a huge reason for not returning NULL depends on a bit of history.

Things were not clean back when C was being invented, and maybe not even on small systems today. The original K&R C did not guarantee NULL would be zero as is usually the case on CPUs with virtual memory. On small "real memory" systems zero may be a valid address making it necessary for "invalid" addresses to be moved to some other OS dependent location. Such would really be accepted by the CPU, just not generated in the normal scheme of things. Perhaps a very high memory address. I can even see a hidden array called `extern const long NULL[1];` allowing NULL to become the address of this otherwise unused array.

Back then you saw a lot of `if ( ptr != NULL )` statements rather than `if ( ptr )` for people serious about writing portable code.

Comment: C *still* doesn't guarantee that a null pointer has the same representation as zero. What it does guarantee is that a an integer constant expression with the value zero, or such an expression cast to `void*`, is a null pointer constant. At compile time, such a constant will be converted to a null pointer -- whatever representation that has. Recommended reading: Section 5 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/). And personally, I still write `if (ptr != NULL)` rather than `if (ptr)` -- not for portability, but for clarity.

Comment: Agreed. I do too, unless, maybe, I'm writing for a POSIX environment where all the existing code does not. Then I'll follow the established convention.