# What does 1L mean?

Tags: c, literals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “-1L” mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115566/what-does-1l-mean-in-c)

What does "0L", "1L" mean in C ?
How is it different from "0" and "1" ?
Is there other literals than "L" with similar function in C ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's an integer constant that has a `long int` type instead of `int`.

> **C11, § 6.4.4.1 Integer constants #1**
>
> *long-suffix: one of `l` `L`*

Comment: Thank you, I can't upvote you due to low rep

Comment: *long int n = 2147483648: if int is 32 bits (or less), there is an overflow*. What are you saying? In C99 and C11, if `2147483648` cannot fit in an `int`, its type is then `long` or `long long` (the first where it can fit). See 6.4.4.1p5 in both C99 and C11.

Comment: “This rule does not exist in C99 and C11 anymore” The rule is still there in C99 and C11, with lists of types to try that include `long long`, that are different for decimal and octal/hexadecimal, and that do not include any unsigned type in the decimal case. Apart from that, it's still the same rule, and `long int n = 2147483648` is not undefined. There exists a type in which `2147483648` can be represented (because it can be represented in `long long`), and the conversion to `long int` is at worse implementation-defined if `long int` is too narrow to hold it.

Comment: Also of note, modern implementations of GCC and of compilers aiming for GCC compatibility such as Clang still use C89's type list by default, making `2147483648 ` an `unsigned long` on archtectures where `long` is 32-bit. http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/01/20/Constants-quiz http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/01/20/Constants-quiz-answers

Comment: @PascalCuoq yes, because by default `gcc` compiles with `-std=gnu89`. But if you switch to `c99`,  `c11`, `gnu99` or `gnu11` then the type would be `long long`.

Comment: My mistake. I've deleted the wrong informations.

Answer (score 11):

The `0L` means 0 in `long` format.

Comment: Thank you, I can't upvote you due to low rep

Comment: @JeremyL: Now you can! ;-)

Answer (score 6):

In the [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (PDF of draft), the suffixes described are in 6.4.4.1 (integer suffixes) and 6.4.4.2 (floating suffixes)

Integer suffixes are `u` (`unsigned`), `l` (lowercase L) (`long`), `ll` (`long long`), `ul` (`unsigned long`), `ull` (`unsigned long long`), `lu` (`long unsigned`), `llu` (`long long unsigned`) and uppercase versions.

Floating suffixes are `f` (`float`) and `l` (`long double`) and uppercase versions.

Comment: Thank you, I can't upvote you due to low rep

Answer (score 4):

The `L` suffix makes it a `long` instead of an `int` literal -- it can be applied to essentially any number (though if the number is large enough that it won't fit in an `int`, it will be a `long` whether you include the suffix or not).

Comment: Thank you, I can't upvote you due to low rep